# Bulk update items in Shared Documents and its subfolders

Tags: powershell

Im trying to use the following ps script to update multiple items in a document list.

I think the example is related to sp 2010.

Anyone who have something to do this with?

```
$SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://localserver/test -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists[“Shared Documents”]
$SPItems = $SPList.Items | Where { $_[“CustomField”] -eq “Yes” } 
foreach($item in $SPItems){
$item[“CustomField”] = “No”
$item.Update()
}
Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment
```

Comment: which version of sharepoint you are on?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try several solutions, here two:

First one:

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://localserver/test
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"]
$SPItems = $SPList.Items | ? { ($_["HTML File Type"] -ne "SharePoint.DocumentSet") -and ($_["CustomField"] -eq "Yes") }
foreach($item in $SPItems){
    $item["CustomField"] = "No"
    $item.Update()
}
```

Source: [Iterate through SharePoint library folders,subfolders and items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961837/iterate-through-sharepoint-library-folders-subfolders-and-items)

Second option:

```
Function GetMyFiles($Folder) {
    Write-Host " + in: "$Folder.Name
    foreach($file in $Folder.Files) {
        if($file["CustomField"] -eq "Yes"){
            Write-Host " `t" $file.Name
            $file["CustomField"] = "No"
            $file.Update()
        }
    }

    #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
    foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder.SubFolders){
        if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms"){
            Write-Host "` t" - NoNewline
            GetMyFiles($Subfolder)
        }
    }

}

$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://localserver/test
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"]
GetMyFiles($SPList.RootFolder)
```

Source: [Iterating through all Document Libraries, Folder and Item using Powershell](https://imughal.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/iterating-through-all-document-libraries-folder-and-item-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you Sergio!
I think second option will work for me since i have subfolders i Shared Documents, but as i see it that example dont look for field, in this case named "CustomField" ? I need it to iterate through all files and sub folders in shared documents, WHERE "CustomFild" is set to "Yes", but only on files. Will that be possible?

Comment: Yes, you are right, an if was missing. I have already added it. It will do what you need. Please mark the answer as correct if it was helpful :)

Comment: Hmm it works perfectly, or without error at least :) Its a start... However its hard to debug on :D ... I have several pdf files within Shared Documents and a subfolder with CustomField = Yes, but the PS script dont change the value to No ...

Comment: If `Write-Host " t" $file.Name` isn't printing the name of those pdf that means that is not entering in the IF for some reason. Has some file been changed to No? Check why

Comment: Roger. The `Write-Host " t" $file.Name` returning `t - NoNewline` :-( I have tried different kind of field types i.e. Single line of Text but without luck..

Comment: Oh maybe its me that isn't making my self clear :) As i understand it, the script will change the value in column named CustomField, if its already = Yes, then change it to No. Isn't that right? Thank you Sergio.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Great. Instead of pdf files i just tried with pptx, but without luck..

Comment: Print with write-host in several lines and look at the cmd to know where it’s failing